# Check for minutes not evenly divided by 5

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a time stored as a decimal(9,2) column in an sql-server 2005 database.

The time is represented like
Time       timeInDecimal
1H 20Min   1.33
1H 30Min   1.50
and so on

I´m looking for an easy way to check whether the number of minutes except whole hours is not evenly divided by 5.
The value I'm hoping to find is where the time is 1H:23Min but not 1H:25MIN.
I just wan´t to compare the minute part of the time.

The way I do now is:

```
RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute,ROUND(timeInDecimal * 60,0),0),108),1) not in ('0','5')
```

But it does hardly seems to be the ideal way to deal with this.

Feels like I can use the modulo operator for this, but how?
Or is there an even better way?

Hope for a quick answer.
Kind Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the modulus operator, twice:

```
ROUND((timeInDecimal % 1) * 60, 0) % 5 <> 0
```

That will:

1. Get the fractional part and convert it to minutes.
2. Round it to the nearest minute (.33 hours -> 20 minutes, not 19.80).
3. Check whether that's divisible by 5.